# Finding Logistic Regression weights from K-Fold CV

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I have a dataset with 36 features and I am using all those features into a logistic regression algorithm inside Fold cross validation. I have K value as 10. Is there any way I can find the weights dedicated to all 36 features of mine at the end of 10th fold in CV? here is my code:

```
    labels = df.columns[2:36]

    X = df[labels]
    y = df['target']

    # use train/test split with different random_state values
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=4)

    logreg = LogisticRegression()
    classifier_pre = cross_val_score(logreg, X, y, cv=20, scoring='precision')
    print("Precision:" ,classifier_pre.mean())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, indexes in python start from 0, so writing `labels = df.columns[2:36]` assumes that your target column has index 1, meaning in human speaking language, it is the second starting from the left (looping over the values, column 36 will be return as column 0). If your target column is the first column starting from the left of your dataframe, you should rather write `labels = df.columns[1:35]`

Some functions, including logistic regression, already have a CV schema implemented in sklearn.linear_model. I advise you to have a look [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html) where you can see how to tune and use it.

You can try something like :

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV

labels = df.columns[1:35] #if indeed your very first column is your target !!

logistic = LogisticRegressionCV(Cs=4, fit_intercept=True, cv=10, verbose =1, random_state=42)
logistic.fit(X, y)
print(logistic.coef_) #weights of each feature
print(logistic.intercept_) #value of intercept
```

One last advise: it is a good idea to use a test set generated by `train_test_split`, but do not train your model on it. Use it only for evaluation at the very end. Meaning that here you should fit your algorithm with `X_train` and `y_train` and evaluate it on `X_test` and `y_test`, instead of replicating the little piece of code I wrote, where the fitting part is done on `X` and `y`, which will lead to an overoptimistic measure of your accuracy if evaluate your model on `X` and `y`...

Answer (score 0):

I got it. We could implement it like this:

```
labels = df.columns[2:35]

X = df[labels]
y = df['target']

kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
logistic = LogisticRegressionCV(Cs=2, fit_intercept=True, cv=kf, verbose =1, random_state=42)
logistic.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Train Coefficient:" , logistic.coef_) #weights of each feature
print("Train Intercept:" , logistic.intercept_) #value of intercept
```

This will give coefficients and intercepts for the given model with CV=10 in KFOLD and LR.

Comment: This can be implemented with any number of folds and we just need to change value of n_splits in k fold.